# Using row chart as a legend to highlight on line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

(This has been asked on the dc.js usergroup 2 or 3 times but never answered)

I have a chart setup sort of like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v8vnjop9/20/).

Instead of using a legend to highlight the lines on the composite chart, I'd like to use the bars on the row chart. So whenever the user hovers over the bar labelled "A", the line for "A" highlights in the same way it would if you hovered over the legend labelled "A".

In the cd.js source I found a mouseover event and the legendHighlight(d) function, but I wasn't able to find a way to get them to work between my row and composite chart.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Code from Fiddle here:

```
    var data = [
        {date: "01/10/2013", Site: "A", Value: 50, Uptime: 0.80},
        {date: "01/10/2013", Site: "B", Value: 42, Uptime: 0.76},
        {date: "01/10/2013", Site: "C", Value: 68, Uptime: 0.84},
        {date: "01/10/2013", Site: "D", Value: 52, Uptime: 0.79},
        {date: "02/10/2013", Site: "A", Value: 49, Uptime: 0.80},
        {date: "02/10/2013", Site: "B", Value: 48, Uptime: 0.78},
        {date: "02/10/2013", Site: "C", Value: 61, Uptime: 0.85},
        {date: "02/10/2013", Site: "D", Value: 58, Uptime: 0.77},
        {date: "03/10/2013", Site: "A", Value: 48, Uptime: 0.83},
        {date: "03/10/2013", Site: "B", Value: 45, Uptime: 0.89},
        {date: "03/10/2013", Site: "C", Value: 49, Uptime: 0.91},
        {date: "03/10/2013", Site: "D", Value: 53, Uptime: 0.92},
        {date: "04/10/2013", Site: "A", Value: 42, Uptime: 0.82},
        {date: "04/10/2013", Site: "B", Value: 38, Uptime: 0.76},
        {date: "04/10/2013", Site: "C", Value: 61, Uptime: 0.83},
        {date: "04/10/2013", Site: "D", Value: 78, Uptime: 0.68}
    ]

var ndx = crossfilter(data)

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;

data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

//Dimensions
var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.date;
});
var siteDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.Site;
});
siteGroup = siteDim.group();
var Value = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
    return d.Value
});
var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;

// Gets all the site names
sites = [];
groupToParse = eval(siteGroup).top(Infinity);
for(var i in groupToParse){
    sites.push(groupToParse[i]["key"]);
}
sites.sort();

valueBySite = siteDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){
    return d.Value;
});

/*****************
Uptime line chart
*****************/

var site_uptime_Ave = dateDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

avgBySite = [];
for(var i in sites){
    avgBySite[i] = dateDim.group().reduce(
        function(inSite){
            return function (p, v) {
                if(inSite == v.Site){
                    p.total += v.Uptime;
                    ++p.count;
                    p.average = d3.round((p.total / p.count), 2);
                }return p;
            };
        }(sites[i]),

        function(inSite){
            return function (p, v) {
                if(inSite == v.Site){
                    p.total -= v.Uptime;
                    --p.count;
                    p.average = d3.round((p.total / p.count), 2);
                }return p;
            };
        }(sites[i]),
        reduceInitial
        );
}

var uptimeLineChart = dc.compositeChart("#chart-line-uptime");

composites = []
for(var i in avgBySite){
    composites[i] = dc.lineChart(uptimeLineChart)
                      .group(avgBySite[i], sites[i])
    .valueAccessor(function(p){
        return p.value.average;  
    });
}

uptimeLineChart.width(500).height(200)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(0).y(0).gap(5))
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .margins( {top: 10, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 50 })
    //.elasticY(true)
    .shareColors(true)
    .compose(composites);

//------------------------------------
// Row chart
//------------------------------------
theRowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row-value");
theRowChart.width(500).height(200)
           .dimension(siteDim)
           .group(valueBySite);



// Render charts
dc.renderAll();



print_filter(valueBySite);

// Functions for reduce to give an average
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    p.total += v.Uptime;
    ++p.count;
    p.average = d3.round((p.total / p.count), 2);
    return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    p.total -= v.Uptime;
    --p.count;
    p.average = d3.round((p.total / p.count), 2);
    return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
    return {
        total: 0,
        count: 0,
        average: 0,
    };
}

// Prints a filter
function print_filter(filter) {
    var f = eval(filter);
    if (typeof (f.length) != "undefined") {} else {}
    if (typeof (f.top) != "undefined") {
        f = f.top(Infinity);
    } else {}
    if (typeof (f.dimension) != "undefined") {
        f = f.dimension(function (d) {
            return "";
        }).top(Infinity);
    } else {}
    console.log(filter + "(" + f.length + ") = " + JSON.stringify(f).replace("[", "[\n\t").replace(/}\,/g, "},\n\t").replace("]", "\n]"));
}
```

Comment: You might want to use vanilla d3.js to do this.  You would have more control. All you need to do is to add a mouseover event to each bar, so something like .on("mouseover", function {}).  You can see this in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7557092) except it's an on click event.

Comment: The method @user1614080 outlines will work just as well with dc.js, as dc is just a leaky abstraction over d3. It would start `chart.selectAll("rect.bar").on("mouseover")...` If you can point to the earlier discussion that'd help.